# KCFinder, uploadURL and uploadDir

Tags: kcfinder

i have a website 'site.be' and the admin panel for that domain is on 'admin.site.be' now i have KCFinder for some time but never get it right working.

On this moment i see the files but no preview of them, also the uploader is not working (unknow error). When i select a photo i get '/kcfinder/http://site.be/hosting/admin/photo.jpg' back from the domain

Can someone explain what this 2 settings do?

Greathings

Comment: I think your problem is just a file path problem, because `/kcfinder/http://site.be/hosting/admin/photo.jpg` starts as an absolute path and also contains the http protocol which is a Url (webpath)

Comment: Where do you see the files?

Comment: What happens when you try to upload? Is there any error message?

Comment: What is "uploadURL" and "uploadDir" set to now?

Comment: KCfinder is here:
[WEBROOT]/admin/ckeditor

The files must be in
[WEBROOT]/hosting/admin/

Webroot is the domain and the subdomain "admin.site.be" has it's root in the admin folder

Comment: $_CONFIG['uploadDir'] = 'http//'.$onlyHostName['domain'].'/hosting/admin';

Comment: 'uploadURL' => "../../hosting/admin",